# RunTime Error '70' Permission Denied in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am using VB6. The tool that i have created extracts few zip files and unzips them onto a folder that i create locally.In the clean up part of my code, i have deleted the folder using this code

```
If (f.FolderExists(path + "Extracted Files") = True) Then
     f.DeleteFolder (path + "Extracted Files")
End If
```

When i run this code, i get an error Run Time Error '70' and Permission Denied  in the line f.DeleteFolder(path + 'Extracted Files').

Where am i going wrong ? Or do i need to create the folder with a different permission ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps one or more of the files is read-only?  Use the optional force parameter to force deletion:

```
f.DeleteFolder (path + "Extracted Files"), True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a library written in another language to extract the files? Verify that any pointer was open, it is likely that some file is opened, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Registry Editor by typing `regedit` in Start Search or command prompt.
2. In Registry Editor, navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
   ```
3. Locate the following `DWORD` registry subkey in the right pane: `EnableLUA`
4. Double click on `EnableLUA` 
   On value prompt, set value to `0`.
5. Exit from Registry Editor.
6. Restart the computer.
7. To enable the UAC again, set value of `EnableLUA` to `1`.